# String value cout'ing as a spade?

Tags: c++, arrays

Im trying to use this function to grab the version of any file but my problem is when i cout the value it appears as a spade. I know theres nothing wrong with the way im printing the value on the screen so it must be something inside my function....i just have no idea what it could be. I tried changing from string to a char array for CompleteVer but there were some issues.

```
string GetFileVersion(HANDLE hprocess)
{
    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO* FFI;
    UINT FFISize;
    BYTE* VersionInfo;
    char Path[MAX_PATH];
    int VersionSeg[4] = {0};
    string CompleteVer;

    if(GetModuleFileNameEx(hprocess,0,Path,sizeof(Path)))
        if(int FilePropSize = GetFileVersionInfoSize(Path,0))
        {
            VersionInfo = new BYTE[FilePropSize];
            if(GetFileVersionInfo(Path,0,FilePropSize,VersionInfo))
                if(VerQueryValue(VersionInfo,"\\",(void**)&FFI,&FFISize))
                {
                    VersionSeg[0] = HIWORD(FFI->dwFileVersionMS);
                    VersionSeg[1] = LOWORD(FFI->dwFileVersionMS);
                    VersionSeg[2] = HIWORD(FFI->dwFileVersionLS);
                    VersionSeg[3] = LOWORD(FFI->dwFileVersionLS);
                    delete[] VersionInfo;

                    for(int x = 0;x < 4;x++)
                    {
                        CompleteVer += VersionSeg[x];
                    }

                    return CompleteVer;
                }
            else
                return "3";
        }
        else
            return "2";
    else
        return "1";
}
```

Output:  ♠

Comment: Definitely one of the more macabre forms of UB I've seen yet.

Comment: How do you know it's Ace of Spade..? That's just spade...

Comment: What are `HIWORD` and `LOWORD`? What are the values in `VersionSeg`?

Comment: @Potatoswatter, `HIWORD` and `LOWORD` are Win32 macros for extracting halves from a `DWORD`. It's common for things to pack two `WORD`s into one parameter etc.

Comment: @chris Up to you, but that seems to make everything as endianness-sensitive and obfuscated as possible. If you have a string of bytes in a file, treat it as bytes!

Comment: @Potatoswatter, It usually isn't up to you. For example, see the [WM_COMMAND message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591(v=vs.85).aspx). All of this is sent to your window, and if you send one to another window, you're expected to form each part in that way. I'm not saying a word against everything past those first three words, though. I guess you could choose to use an API that does not force that down your throat :p

Comment: @chris But that's an OS message, and the question seems to involve a file format. Maybe I misunderstand… it's not really important.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, `HIWORD` and `LOWORD` are used all over the API. I just thought that one made a good example. I can't say much in relation to this question, as I'm unfamiliar with these.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're grabbing some `int` values from a structure and appending them to a string without first converting to characters. If the values you're grabbing are ASCII, then you should declare `VersionSeg` as `char [4]`, and if they're not, then you need to do something like adding to `'0'`. And check that they are decimal digits less than 10 while you're at it.

Comment: Also, OP probably has to actually convert the numbers into an ASCII string. Each number in `VersionSeg` probably contains more than one digit's worth.

Comment: @yzt Impossible to tell. He's not adding decimal points between them. Anyway the gist is the same.